# best way to access IabHelper from my customs list view adapter

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, singleton, static-members

I have a IabHelper in my MainActivity which I'm using to for initial setup and for querying my in-app products.

Then I'm creating a listview with all the products, every item in my list view has a "BUY" button which should trigger a purchase for this item.

I'm using a custom adapter and I added a onClickListener in my getView function.

Now my question is what is the best way to use the IabHelper member that is declared in my MainActivity to start a purchase from my CustomAdapter class ?

- singleton
- declare the IabHelper in my Application class
- use a static variable (but then I should do it to all the IabListeners?)
- any other idea...?

Comment: I would use singleton in application extended class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use interface, I have done like this:

create interface in adapter:

```
public interface IABHelperProvider {
    public IabHelper getHelper();
}
```

then implement it to main activity and override method getHelper():

```
@Override
public IabHelper getHelper() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mHelper;
}
```

and call it in adapter

```
mHelper = ((IABHelperProvider)getActivity()).getHelper();
```

This starts purchase flow

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(yourcontext, id, 10001,   
                mPurchaseFinishedListener, "sometext");
```

Here is my mPurchaseFinishedListener

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener 
= new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, 
            Purchase purchase) 
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }      
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            consumeItem();
            mBuyButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
};
```

For the end consume item using to unlock next purchase of same item:

```
public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

private IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener 
= new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
            Inventory inventory) {


        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure
        } else {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU), 
                    mConsumeFinishedListener);
            if(inventory.hasPurchase(mBook.getAppStoreProductId())){

            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: what about all the listeners that you need to use ?

Comment: Probably you need to run this flow for each item in your adapter with some kind of progressbar while it won't finish. mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(), someid, 10001,mPurchaseFinishedListener, "sometext"); And check for available items u can before putting them to list view

Comment: the reason that I need to access the Helper from my listview is that I have a "BUY" button on every row. once the user clicks a "BUY" button, I want to start the purchase flow. the problem is that the helper and its all listeners are defined in my main activity.

Comment: what can I use instead of the getActivity() and mPurchaseFinishedListener ? should I pass both params to the Adapter in the CTOR ?

Comment: Instead of getActivity() use adapters context.  mPurchaseFinishedListener is my purcasing flow:

Comment: where did you declare the listeners ? in your MainActivity ?

Comment: to be specific, where should I declare OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener? in MainActivity or in my Adapter? or maybe declare it in MainActivity and pass it to my adapter in the CTOR

Comment: I think you may declare it in a adapter, but as far as i know, you can run only one purchase flow, because it asynctask. so in this case yo can run some dialog to prevent starting runing another flow before first finished